# Can we upload scorm pacakge in our lms system and store course materials in our db?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2, scorm-cloud-api

I am making one LMS system and I want to support SCORM in my LMS system. when I searched about that, I got SCORM authoring tools which are expensive for us.

basically, I want to implement features like uploading a SCORM file in my LMS system and storing that SCORM file's course materials in my DB. so the user can access it.

Is there any alternative soultion except scorm authoring tools for that implementaion?? if yes then please help me i will be thankfull for that.

Answer (score 2):

On the LMS side you will need a SCORM content player. This is generally a system that handles importing SCORM packages, providing a way to launch those packages, and then the SCORM Runtime API that is used by the content to track data about the learner actions, etc. You may want to consider integrating with something like SCORM Cloud rather than attempting to build a fully compliant SCORM player on your own. (Full disclosure: I work for the company that runs SCORM Cloud, Rustici Software.) See https://rusticisoftware.com/solutions/lmss/

Answer (score 0):

LMS SCORM support is big and complicated. There's a reason you don't see too many DIY options out there -- it's a pain to properly implement. If you want full SCORM conformance, especially for multiple editions of SCORM (1.2, 2004), Brian's answer (SCORM Cloud) is the way to go. You can also try extracting the SCORM codebase from open-source LMSs like Moodle or Ilias, but the amount of work required is not insignificant and may not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to scormPLAYER, a SCORM engine than can be integrated with your LMS and allow it to play SCORM content, as well as manage user tracking and other capabilities.

https://welcomenext.com/scormplayer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).